# How does this website know my GOOGLE Search String

Tags: javascript, seo, search-engine

I recently went to the WROX forum. I was led there by GOOGLE. On the top of the page I got this message

```
Welcome,  user.
Your Google search for 'bosh iis' brought you to Wrox Forum
```

Out of curiosity, does anyone know how could they track this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They can read the [HTTP referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) header that contains the search string.

Simplifying a bit: someone clicks a link on a Google search results page (which has the search query as part of the URL) to some other page. This page can read the URL of the previous page (which was the Google search).

Using the same technique web developers can discover which pages have links to their page.

Comment: Is access to this blocked by some firewalls/AntiVirus'?

Comment: No, it is part of the HTTP header, sent by the browser. When you are on page `foo.com` and click a link to `bar.com`, the browser will add `Referer: foo.com` header that can be read by `bar.com`.

Comment: @Joy, some ativiruses and firewalls can clear `Referrer` header. moreover browsers itself may remove that header if they have such option.

Answer (score 3):

From the HTTP header the website can get the referrer data, which means the page the originated the request for the page you are currently looking at, this way the website knows it was referred from Google, and by parsing the URL it can find out your search query.

More on HTTP referer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer